# spring batch parallel processing & Liferay webservice API

Tags: multithreading, spring, liferay, spring-batch, scheduling

I have a `spring-batch` Job that runs on a standalone `api`, it is a multithreaded batch that creates `Users` on `APP-1` and communicates with liferay through web-services to create `Users` on the liferay side.

The job works fine it creates a `User` on a average of `0.45`s although it needs approximetly `2.4s` to be created on liferay (these data depends on my network installation).

An incident happen, while the job is executing for a huge batch of users, someone restarted the liferay server. On the job side there were `Skippable Exceptions` for some threads, after that i had some performance issues from the batch size and the increase of time to create a user from an average `0.45s` to almost `2.3s`.

My question is :

In the above installation , if a thread is skipped on the `writer` , will spring batch eliminate it from the thread pool, or would it continue executing ?

What could be the reasons behing the performance issue besides that ?

Thanks , any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: 1.  Have you done any profiling to find out what the delay is?
2.  To answer your specific question depends on how you've configured your `TaskExecutor`...

Comment: @MichaelMinella it is a simple Asynchronous Task Executor with a concurrency limit of 10.The job Took 36 hours of execution I didn't have time to do any profiling